# How to upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04?

Tags: 14.04

I know there are instructions for upgrading from Ubuntu Ubuntu **16.04.6 LTS** to **19.04** as shown in the tutorial below.

https://www.ostechnix.com/upgrade-ubuntu-single-command/

But I would like to perform on my operating system an upgrade from version **16.04.6 LTS** to **18.04.3 LTS**, how? And please, how could I perform the procedures?

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 16, 18 or 19. 16.04 and 18.04 are LTS, 16.10 and 18.10 are EoL.

Comment: complete correction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
do-release-upgrade
```

should upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04.

But success is not guaranteed. There are too many changes between the releases to be always smooth. Make a backup first.

Comment: Make a backup and verify the backup matches the contents of the source. Do it again to different media or the cloud, and verify that. Then and only then proceed with potentially risky processes.

Comment: @Pilot6 is it necessary to run an update/upgrade prior to running do-release-upgrade or will it handle it all?

Comment: It is recommended to run `upgrade` first, but it will work without.